# Can I change "public-dir" in composer.json to a subfolder of the public directory safely in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, assets

Main purpose is:

1) in twig templates to use simple code `asset('img/some.jpg')` without the second argument,that return path to `web/dir1/dir2/img/some.jpg`

2) when we run `asset:install` without argument in console, it store all bundle assets to `web/dir1/dir2/`

All our assets are stored in a directory that has a big level of nesting(the child theme of wordpress). 
We don’t want to write this whole path in the parameter of asset() in twig templates.

For Example images is stored in `web/dir1/die2/img/`
We want write `asset(img/some.jpg)`, without handling of the second parameter.

Documentation says, we can just point in config.yml the directory with assets:

```
assets:
    base_path: ‘web/dir1/dir2/img’
```

But it breaks third party bundles, because when we run `assets:install` in console, It just copy(or link) all assets of bundles in the true public directory. But bundles use the same base_path in asset() function, that point  to `web/dir1/dir2/`.

assets:install can take argument with public directory. If it is ommited, command takes `public-dir` from composer.json.

So we want to set  parameter `public-dir`.

It seems strange: I thought this is THE MAIN PUBLIC DIRECTORY PARAMETER and it must not point anywhere except web/(in my case).

I tried to find anything in github: these changes will break bundle WebServerBundle, which we don’t use and don't plan to use. It is not enough.And I could not find other reasons not to do it.

Is it a bad practice or a normal? 
Can it break some code in any bundles?

I wanna know any opinion: this can be the cause of problems or I should not worry about that?

Comment: Have you seen https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory ?

Comment: Yes, I have. But there is nothing about using this parameter in bundles.

Comment: If bundle use `asset(img/some.jpg)` there is not problem

Comment: We have no problem with the public directory. We just want to change this param to subdir in the public dir. It is work for us. There is only a little feeling  that we do something wrong. And It seems that this parameter affect  nothing  except the console command asset:install and web server bundle. If so , I'll be glad.

Comment: The only problem I can think of is that if a bundle uses $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir(). '/public/' would then fail...

Comment: In controller `$request->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT').$request->getBasePath()` this works

Answer (score 0):

It has been two years since we did this trick. Everything works fine.